# execl with wget, child process, unix - why does it not work

Tags: c++, unix, exec, fork, wget

So I am trying to execute wget in a separate child process which I am duplicating with fork as follows:

```
  int child;
  pid_t child = fork();
if ( child == 0 ) { // no errors
  bool done = false;  // set to false
  while (!done) { // while not true do
  execl("wget", "someurl", NULL);
  done = true;  // since dl finished
 }
 cout << "DL Finished\n";  // to see if child was successful
}
else if ( child != 0 ) { // errors
```

Any apparent errors that you can point out in this code? If it matters, this is inside a void function that I am calling in main what is happening is that it is not downloading and it displays "DL Finished", but does **not** execute wget - *then* terminal takes over.

This is executed on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. I have previously inside the same void function used **child** to execute "ls" which works properly, that is with me telling it the whole path of ls (/bin/ls). I read that not providing the full path will make it search for the command, which is what I want.

Comment: Try using the full path of wget in the exec call.

Comment: When `fork` return non-zero, it's not necessarily an error. Most of the time its the process id of the new child-process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that not providing the full path will make it search for the
>   command

That happens for `execlp`. Also, by convention the first argument should be the name of the executable. So you could try:

```
execlp("wget", "wget", "someurl", NULL);
     ^          ^^^^^
```

---

As a side note, your `while (!done)` is wrong. That's not how you wait for a program to finish. In fact, once you call `exec` the `while` is gone: another process "replaces" your own. So you can think of it "`exec` is a function that doesn't return". The standard way is to `wait(2)` in the parent until the child dies.

---

As a second side note, if all you want is to `wget` something and wait until the `wget` is done, the `system(3)` is possibly more appropriate:

```
system("wget someurl");
```

Comment: You are right, thank you! As for the while (!done), do you have any hints/suggestions on how to make it wait for the download to finish? (will add as answer once I am allowed)

Comment: I will wait a bit as you suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you pass to `execl` are what will be the `argv` array to the new process `main` function. And as you know the first entry in `argv` is the program name itself.

So what you need to do is:

```
execlp("wget", "wget", "someurl", NULL);
```

Also, if all went well the `exec` family of function does not return, so any code after the `exec` call will not run.